# Creating a for loop which check if a element is in the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to construct a for loop where it checks if the element is in the dictionary.

```py
dict = {}

if element1 in dict:
    dict[element1].add(element2)
elif element1 not in dict:
    dict[element1]=set().add(element2)
elif element2 in dict:
    dict[element2].add(element1)
elif element 2 not in dict:
    dict[element2]=set().add(element1)
```

The dictionary I want to get has the following data structure; 
`dict={element 1:{element 2, element 3}, element2:{element3, element1}, ...}`(so, set inside the dictionary).

Comment: So you want to build this dict out of a list of (v1, v2) graph edge tuples or something?

Comment: Your second and third elif statements are non-reachable. Could you provide a better example ?

Comment: If I run the code above, I would get `{element1:{element2},element2:{element1}}`

Comment: @Ry- Yes! the original data has following strcture; `[(element1,element2), (element3, element1), (element 4, element 2)]`. So, I guess sorting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are merely searching for a way to add elements to a set inside a dictionary, creating the set if it does not exist yet. You can use DefaultDict to do that for you.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict = defaultdict(set)
edges = [("element1", "element2"), ("element3", "element1"), ("element4", "element2")]
for edge in edges:
    dict[edge[0]].add(edge[1])
    dict[edge[1]].add(edge[0]) # Remove if graph is directed
```

Gives:

```
{
  'element1': {'element3', 'element2'},
  'element2': {'element4', 'element1'},
  'element3': {'element1'},
  'element4': {'element2'}
}
```

Comment: You can also unpack `for a, b in edges` to be able to write `dict[a].add(b)` and `dict[b].add(a)`. (Another aside: `dict` is kind of a confusing variable name for a dict, since it’s also the type.)

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code

```
elements = [("value1", "value2"), ("value3", "value4"), ("value4", "value2")]
sorted_elements = {}

for element1, element2 in elements:
    sorted_elements.setdefault(element1, set()); sorted_elements.setdefault(element2, set())
    sorted_elements[element1].add(element2); sorted_elements[element2].add(element1)

print(sorted_elements)
```

and it will output

```py
{'element1': {'element2', 'element3'}, 'element2': {'element1', 'element4'}, 'element3': {'element1'}, 'element4': {'element2'}}
```